# How to trigger forked pull request in jenkins build?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, pull-request

I just started to use forked branches instead of branches inside my primary repo, and when I try to pull request to main repo it triggers jenkins but it always fail. When I look at the log it fails to grab branch from my forked repo.

[image]

Is there anything i'm doing wrong?